# Upgraded to Cassandra 1.1.0 and could not find CassandraStorage()

Tags: java, hadoop, cassandra, apache-pig

**This issue seems to have been resolved in the latest Cassandra 1.1.2 but I shall leave it here for those still on 1.1.0...**

I have just upgraded to Cassandra 1.1.0, compiling it from source, and now I cannot find the CassandraStorage() class anywhere, and the contrib directory has disappeared!

May I know where I could find it? This class is important and utmost essential to the operation of Pig and Hadoop via Cassandra.

Also, executing the pig_cassandra from the examples directory produced the error that the CassandraStorage() could not be found. Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage

Comment: I have tried to recompile, and it still gives the same error. I am using the loader bundled with the Cassandra distribution.
In the /path/to/cassandra/examples/pig/bin/pig_cassandra